# Links to Controller methods: CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm following this tutorial on CodeIgniter:

http://ie.mirror.twsweb-int.com/codeigniter/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

4th page of tutorial:

http://ie.mirror.twsweb-int.com/codeigniter/user_guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html

In the 4th page of the tutorial, he mentions that you should create your own successful entry page.

I want to create a link on the success.php that links back to the index page (calls news_index).
IE in terms of URLs, I want a link that goes from

```
http://example.com/codeigniter/index.php/news/create
```

to

```
http://example.com/codeigniter/index.php/news/
```

How are dynamic URLs like that made on CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First load the URL helper in your controller or Autoload file.

Then use the `site_url()` function and just pass news.

```
<?php echo site_url('news');?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at this page - http://ie.mirror.twsweb-int.com/codeigniter/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html you can see how the `site_url()` function works.

You just echo site_url('controller/method/segment1/segment2/etc'); so if you wanted to link to the `http://example.com/codeigniter/index.php/news/` page you can do

`<?php echo site_url('news'); ?>`

and if you wanted to link to the `http://example.com/codeigniter/index.php/news/create` you can do

`<?php echo site_url('news/create'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

you configure them on the routes.php on your codeigniter files.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `site_url/base_url` in `config.php` and load the URL helper in `autoload.php` file.